# Firebase Crashlytics causes my unity game to crash on the splash screen

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crashlytics

**The game stops working at all. it crashes from the startup splash screen and I got the following Errors using adb logcat:**
this happened just after I added the crashlytics package to the project. I researched everywhere to find a solution without founding any.

```
Caused by java.lang.Error: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Version '2020.3.14f1 (d0d1bb862f9d)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'armeabi-v7a'
Build fingerprint: 'google/android_x86/x86:7.1.2/N2G48C/4565141:/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm'
Timestamp: 2021-09-08 03:25:51+0100
pid: 3674, tid: 3786, name: Thread-8  >>> com.STCODE.HbaleOuBanet <<<
uid: 10066
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x1dec
    r0  00000000  r1  00001dec  r2  00000030  r3  00000001
    r4  00000000  r5  072df22a  r6  a360cc78  r7  a3af8d80
    r8  c77e5008  r9  971031fc  r10 00000c3e  r11 974dea30
    ip  072d1c60  sp  974dea20  lr  04378f9c  pc  04146297

backtrace:
      #00 pc 00146297  /data/app/com.STCODE.HbaleOuBanet-1/lib/arm/libunity.so (BuildId: 1b8e7b418ebe417920a0c394d97692101732bf8c)
      #01 pc 00d1092c  /data/app/com.STCODE.HbaleOuBanet-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (SystemInfo_GetGraphicsDeviceType_m8E30DF86F5AE77EBB1752A55B183890C3ACA8443+76) (BuildId: 6c3cfe3a25ae442a51d2edf07725508d0201b537)
      #02 pc 00d108bc  /data/app/com.STCODE.HbaleOuBanet-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (SystemInfo_get_graphicsDeviceType_mC207E6B2221AD5AB39831C2412FF7FBD2F43CC02+24) (BuildId: 6c3cfe3a25ae442a51d2edf07725508d0201b537)
      #03 pc 00ff7310  /data/app/com.STCODE.HbaleOuBanet-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (Metadata__ctor_m6B36A0DB8C3359A69E6302C6B9D3FE4160D4C97C+500) (BuildId: 6c3cfe3a25ae442a51d2edf07725508d0201b537)
      #04 pc 00fed228  /data/app/com.STCODE.HbaleOuBanet-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (MetadataBuilder_GenerateMetadataJSON_m07C6061E12A94155286C4A97B19C8377F3CF13CF+148) (BuildId: 6c3cfe3a25ae442a51d2edf07725508d0201b537)
      #05 pc 00fecc5c  /data/app/com.STCODE.HbaleOuBanet-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (AndroidImpl__ctor_m4E6CBDE90170A15B3E4D511BB2BD3A3658E9EB6C+812) (BuildId: 6c3cfe3a25ae442a51d2edf07725508d0201b537)
      #06 pc 00ff5df0  /data/app/com.STCODE.HbaleOuBanet-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (Impl_Make_m74302D58D6B7AF07BD008DCA5EBE99A35C313E73+224) (BuildId: 6c3cfe3a25ae442a51d2edf07725508d02<truncated: 9551 chars>
       at libunity.0x146297()
       at libil2cpp.SystemInfo_GetGraphicsDeviceType_m8E30DF86F5AE77EBB1752A55B183890C3ACA8443(SystemInfo_GetGraphicsDeviceType_m8E30DF86F5AE77EBB1752A55B183890C3ACA8443:76)
       at libil2cpp.SystemInfo_get_graphicsDeviceType_mC207E6B2221AD5AB39831C2412FF7FBD2F43CC02(SystemInfo_get_graphicsDeviceType_mC207E6B2221AD5AB39831C2412FF7FBD2F43CC02:24)
       at libil2cpp.Metadata__ctor_m6B36A0DB8C3359A69E6302C6B9D3FE4160D4C97C(Metadata__ctor_m6B36A0DB8C3359A69E6302C6B9D3FE4160D4C97C:500)
       at libil2cpp.MetadataBuilder_GenerateMetadataJSON_m07C6061E12A94155286C4A97B19C8377F3CF13CF(MetadataBuilder_GenerateMetadataJSON_m07C6061E12A94155286C4A97B19C8377F3CF13CF:148)
       at libil2cpp.AndroidImpl__ctor_m4E6CBDE90170A15B3E4D511BB2BD3A3658E9EB6C(AndroidImpl__ctor_m4E6CBDE90170A15B3E4D511BB2BD3A3658E9EB6C:812)
       at libil2cpp.Impl_Make_m74302D58D6B7AF07BD008DCA5EBE99A35C313E73(Impl_Make_m74302D58D6B7AF07BD008DCA5EBE99A35C313E73:224)
       at libil2cpp.PlatformAccessor__cctor_mDE31046115F3B54F58511CDE0306346A0B82AD5D(PlatformAccessor__cctor_mDE31046115F3B54F58511CDE0306346A0B82AD5D:260)
       at libil2cpp.RuntimeInvoker_FalseVoid_t700C6383A2A510C2CF4DD86DABD5CA9FF70ADAC5(void (*)(), MethodInfo const*, void*, void**)(RuntimeInvoker_FalseVoid_t700C6383A2A510C2CF4DD86DABD5CA9FF70ADAC5:48)
       at libil2cpp.il2cpp::vm::Runtime::Invoke(MethodInfo const*, void*, void**, Il2CppException**)(Invoke:312)
       at libil2cpp.il2cpp::vm::Runtime::ClassInit(Il2CppClass*)(ClassInit:448)
       at libil2cpp.il2cpp_codegen_runtime_class_init(Il2CppClass*)(il2cpp_codegen_runtime_class_init:20)
       at libil2cpp.Crashlytics_Initialize_mD0B17607778B519ED69DE320811D42655F90B247(Crashlytics_Initialize_mD0B17607778B519ED69DE320811D42655F90B247:140)
       at libil2cpp.RuntimeInvoker_FalseVoid_t700C6383A2A510C2CF4DD86DABD5CA9FF70ADAC5(void (*)(), MethodInfo const*, void*, void**)(RuntimeInvoker_FalseVoid_t700C6383A2A510C2CF4DD86DABD5CA9FF70ADAC5:48)
       at libil2cpp.il2cpp::vm::Runtime::Invoke(MethodInfo const*, void*, void**, Il2CppException**)(Invoke:312)
       at libil2cpp.il2cpp::vm::InvokeConvertThis(MethodInfo const*, void*, void**, Il2CppException**)(InvokeConvertThis:112)
       at libil2cpp.il2cpp::vm::Runtime::InvokeConvertArgs(MethodInfo const*, void*, Il2CppObject**, int, Il2CppException**)(InvokeConvertArgs:964)
       at libil2cpp.il2cpp::vm::Runtime::InvokeArray(MethodInfo const*, void*, Il2CppArray*, Il2CppException**)(InvokeArray:76)
       at libil2cpp.il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Reflection::MonoMethod::InternalInvoke(Il2CppReflectionMethod*, Il2CppObject*, Il2CppArray*, Il2CppException**)(InternalInvoke:708)
       at libil2cpp.MonoMethod_InternalInvoke_mFF7E631020CDD3B1CB47F993ED05B4028FC40F7E(MonoMethod_InternalInvoke_mFF7E631020CDD3B1CB47F993ED05B4028FC40F7E:60)
       at libil2cpp.MonoMethod_Invoke_mD6E222F8DAB5483E6640B8E399A56B366635B923(MonoMethod_Invoke_mD6E222F8DAB5483E6640B8E399A56B366635B923:604)
       at libil2cpp.VirtFuncInvoker5<Il2CppObject*, Il2CppObject*, int, Binder_t2BEE27FD84737D1E79BC47FD67F6D3DD2F2DDA30*, ObjectU5BU5D_tC1F4EE0DB0B7300255F5FD4AF64FE4C585CF5ADE*, CultureInfo_t1B787142231DB79ABDCE0659823F908A040E9A98*>::Invoke(unsigned short, Il2CppObject*, Il2CppObject*, int, Binder_t2BEE27FD84737D1E79BC47FD67F6D3DD2F2DDA30*, ObjectU5BU5D_tC1F4EE0DB0B7300255F5FD4AF64FE4C585CF5ADE*, CultureInfo_t1B787142231DB79ABDCE0659823F908A040E9A98*)(Invoke:264)
       at libil2cpp.MethodBase_Invoke_m5DA5E74F34F8FFA8133445BAE0266FD54F7D4EB3(MethodBase_Invoke_m5DA5E74F34F8FFA8133445BAE0266FD54F7D4EB3:108)
       at libil2cpp.FirebaseApp_InitializeCrashlyticsIfPresent_m28C2D06F823206C421BF3D241335A8FA4D26A91B(FirebaseApp_InitializeCrashlyticsIfPresent_m28C2D06F823206C421BF3D241335A8FA4D26A91B:908)
       at libil2cpp.FirebaseApp_U3CCreateAndTrackU3Em__1_m9C34C3C32726662CBE52EDB06D70C5E197AF62A5(FirebaseApp_U3CCreateAndTrackU3Em__1_m9C34C3C32726662CBE52EDB06D70C5E197AF62A5:148)
       at libil2cpp.Func_1_Invoke_mD0192F3F912E371387CD7B196DF85569553486B4_gshared(Func_1_Invoke_mD0192F3F912E371387CD7B196DF85569553486B4_gshared:280)
       at libil2cpp.Dispatcher_Run_TisBoolean_t07D1E3F34E4813023D64F584DFF7B34C9D922F37_m84DBD1DE80B0DB201D4CE357F7010A53D60E2EE8_gshared(Dispatcher_Run_TisBoolean_t07D1E3F34E4813023D64F584DFF7B34C9D922F37_m84DBD1DE80B0DB201D4CE357F7010A53D60E2EE8_gshared:368)
       at libil2cpp.FirebaseHandler_RunOnMainThread_TisBoolean_t07D1E3F34E4813023D64F584DFF7B34C9D922F37_m9D9C566E73448622BD4162A06522653697A773B5_gshared(FirebaseHandler_RunOnMainThread_TisBoolean_t07D1E3F34E4813023D64F584DFF7B34C9D922F37_m9D9C566E73448622BD4162A06522653697A773B5_gshared:636)
       at libil2cpp.FirebaseHandler_RunOnMainThread_TisBoolean_t07D1E3F34E4813023D64F584DFF7B34C9D922F37_m9D9C566E73448622BD4162A06522653697A773B5(Func_1_t76FCDA5C58178ED310C472967481FDE5F47DCF0F*, MethodInfo const*)(FirebaseHandler_RunOnMainThread_TisBoolean_t07D1E3F34E4813023D64F584DFF7B34C9D922F37_m9D9C566E73448622BD4162A06522653697A773B5:28)
       at libil2cpp.FirebaseApp_CreateAndTrack_m7FC684DE29AF92053981EB1323B38DBC4D34AC26(FirebaseApp_CreateAndTrack_m7FC684DE29AF92053981EB1323B38DBC4D34AC26:6056)
       at libil2cpp.FirebaseApp_Create_m9A391D6EC41EE45EAA3CCAE368F182EAD69791ED(FirebaseApp_Create_m9A391D6EC41EE45EAA3CCAE368F182EAD69791ED:508)
       at libil2cpp.FirebaseApp_get_DefaultInstance_mCC924BAC33B68B03C851ACE856930B839F8267D7(FirebaseApp_get_DefaultInstance_mCC924BAC33B68B03C851ACE856930B839F8267D7:320)
```

Comment: Is the error message really `*** *** *** ...` ? I'd say with the given log it is pretty impossible to find out what the exact issue could be ...

Comment: Yes that what is shown in the adb logcat command

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! the problem was in my Firebase initializing script I was declaring Firestore db reference in a field variable before fully load the firebase App. that a lesson to learn!